# Spring Framework, como puedo usar mis @Query personalizadas en el controlador

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

tengo tres `@Query` personalizadas :

```
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.backend.apirest.tienda.models.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.bolsadeideas.springboot.backend.apirest.tienda.models.entity.Usuario;

/**
 * IUsuarioDao
 */
public interface IUsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Long> {

    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.email = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
    Usuario findByEmailandPassword(String email, String password);

    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.usuario = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
    Usuario findByUserandPassword(String usuario, String password);

    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.usuario = ?1")
    Usuario findByUser(String usuario);

}
```

Y querri usarlas en mi controlador, a parte de las funciones que `CrudRepository` me provee.
Entonces estoy intentando implementarlas ya en mi **controlador_usuario**:

```
//existe el email + password
@GetMapping("usuarios/existE/{email}/{password}")
public Usuario exist_e_p(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String password) {

    return null;
}

@GetMapping("usuarios/existU/{usuario}")
public Usuario exist_user(@PathVariable String usuario) {

    return null;
}

@GetMapping("usuarios/existU/{email}")
public Usuario exist_email(@PathVariable String email) {

    return null;
}
```

Pero realmente no se que tengo que poner en el return, si ya he puesto el `@Query` en el Dao.

Espero me puedan resolver esta pequeña duda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifica tu repositorio de la siguiente manera

```
@Query("select u from Usuario u where u.email = :email and u.password = :password")
    Usuario findByEmailandPassword(@Param("email") String email, @Param("password") String password);
```

Y en el controlador usas tu DAO

```
@Autowired
private IUsuarioDao iUsuarioDao;

@GetMapping("usuarios/existE/{email}/{password}")
public Usuario exist_e_p(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String password) {
        return iUsuarioDao.findByEmailandPassword(email,password);
}
```